# "conditionalZip" operator in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Assume that I have two sources:

```
val first = Source(1 :: 2 :: 4 :: 6 :: Nil)
val second = Source(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: 7 :: Nil)
```

Is it possible to create a zip that will pair only elements based on a condition? I mean something like:

```
first.conditionalZip(second, _ == _) // if that method exited
```

That code would take the element from the `first` source and drop elements from the `second` until there is an element that satisfies the condition, and then output a tuple. The result for the above call would be `(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6)`.

Comment: What result would you expect for `first.conditionalZip(second,_ > _)`? Notice that `second` will be traversed looking for an element `< 1`.

Comment: In the above case `first.conditionalZip(second,_ > _)` I would expect that no elements will be emitted since there is no element `< 1` in `first`. Also the resulting stream would hang never finish.

Answer (score 1):

Consider zipping the two Sources, followed by using [`statefulMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/statefulMapConcat.html) to transform the zipped elements in accordance with the condition function, as shown below:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.NotUsed

def popFirstMatch(ls: List[Int], condF: Int => Boolean): (Option[Int], List[Int]) = {
  ls.find(condF) match {
    case None =>
      (None, ls)
    case Some(e) => 
      val idx = ls.indexOf(e)
      if (idx < 0)
        (None, ls)
      else {
        val (l, r) = ls.splitAt(idx)
        (r.headOption, l ++ r.tail)
      }
  }
}

def conditionalZip( first: Source[Int, NotUsed],
                    second: Source[Int, NotUsed],
                    filler: Int,
                    condFcn: (Int, Int) => Boolean ): Source[(Int, Int), NotUsed] = {
    first.zipAll(second, filler, filler).statefulMapConcat{ () =>
      var prevList = List.empty[Int]
      tuple => tuple match { case (e1, e2) =>
        if (e2 != filler) {
          if (e1 != filler && condFcn(e1, e2))
            (e1, e2) :: Nil
          else {
            if (e1 != filler)
              prevList :+= e1
            val (opElem, rest) = popFirstMatch(prevList, condFcn(_, e2))
            prevList = rest
            opElem match {
              case None => Nil
              case Some(e) => (e, e2) :: Nil
            }
          }
        }
        else
          Nil
      }
    }
}
```

Test running:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

// Example 1:
val first = Source(1 :: 2 :: 4 :: 6 :: Nil)
val second = Source(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: 7 :: Nil)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ == _).runForeach(println) 
// (1,1)
// (2,2)
// (4,4)
// (6,6)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ > _).runForeach(println) 
// (4,3)
// (6,4)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ < _).runForeach(println) 
// (1,2)
// (2,3)
// (4,5)
// (6,7)

// Example 2:
val first = Source(3 :: 9 :: 5 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil)
val second = Source(1 :: 3 :: 5 :: 2 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ == _).runForeach(println)
// (3,3)
// (5,5)
// (5,5)
// (6,6)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ > _).runForeach(println)
// (3,1)
// (9,3)
// (5,2)
// (6,5)

conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ < _).runForeach(println)
// (3,5)
// (5,6)
```

A few notes:

1. Method [`zipAll`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/zipAll.html) (available on Akka Stream `2.6`+) zips the two Sources while padding the one with fewer elements with provided "filler" values.  In this case, these fillers are of no interest hence should be assigned a distinct value from actual elements.
2. An internal List, `prevList`, is used within `statefulMapConcat` to store elements from the 1st Source for comparing in following iterations with elements from the 2nd Source.  The `List` can be replaced with a `Set` for better lookup performance if elements within the Sources are distinct.
3. Method `popFirstMatch` is for extracting the first element in the `prevList` that matches the provided partial condition function, returning a Tuple of the element of type Option and the remaining List.
4. NOTE that this is just an illustration of how `statefulMapConcat` may be a solution for the described problem.  Behavior of the sample code may not necessarily match the exact requirement without detailed implementation to either cover all cases or refine the scope of the fairly broad condition function `(Int, Int) => Boolean`.

Comment: Great, although it seems to work a bit different than I've described. For `conditionalZip(first, second, Int.MinValue, _ > _).runForeach(println)`  in Example 1 I would expect no elements printed because there is no element in `second` that is greater than the first element of `first` (1).